# Can I use present perfect passive here?

Tags: passive, perfect-tense

> Laut einer Statistik sind drei Viertel aller Deutschen mindestens einmal im Jahr krank zur Arbeit gegangen worden.

Comment: What is the question in your sentence?

Comment: You should edit your question and ask about the use of present perfect passive in general. Specify this question with your example an tell us, why you're in doubt.

Comment: "gegangen worden" is wrong... or really a really clever pun.

Answer (score 5):

No, this would imply that someone else "walked you" - which does not work in German,  as "gehen" is intransitive.

"sind gegangen" is fully sufficient.

Side note: you could potentially use this sentence ironically to express that someone *forced* you to go to work while being ill. This is grammatically still not correct, but occasionally deliberately used this way. As a non-native speaker I would refrain from trying this, though, until you are really confident in the finer connotations of German grammar.